# How can I find all the cells that have the same values in a multi-dimensional array in octave / matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

How can I find all the cells that have the same values in a multi-dimensional array?

I can get it partially to work with  *result=A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,2)* but I'm not sure how to also include *A(:,:,3)*
I tried *result=A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,2)==A(:,:,3)* but the results come back as all 0 when there should be 1 correct answer
which is where the number *8* is located in the same cell on all the pages of the array.  Note: this is just a test the repeating number could be found multiple times and as different numbers.

**PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab**

See code below:

```
clear all, tic
%graphics_toolkit gnuplot %use this for now it's older but allows zoom
A(:,:,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 9 8]; A(:,:,2)=[9 1 7; 6 5 4; 7 2 8]; A(:,:,3)=[2 4 6; 8 9 1; 3 5 8] 
[i j k]=size(A)
for ii=1:k
    maxamp(ii)=max(max(A(:,:,ii)))
    Ainv(:,:,ii)=abs(A(:,:,ii)-maxamp(ii));%the extra max will get the max value of all values in array
end

%result=A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,2)==A(:,:,3)
result=A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,2)
result=double(result); %turns  logical index into double to do find
[row col page] = find(result) %gives me the col, row, page
```

This is the output it gives me:

```
>>>A =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   9   8

ans(:,:,2) =

   9   1   7
   6   5   4
   7   2   8

ans(:,:,3) =

   2   4   6
   8   9   1
   3   5   8

i =  3
j =  3
k =  3
maxamp =  9
maxamp =

   9   9

maxamp =

   9   9   9

result =

   0   0   0
   0   1   0
   1   0   1

row =

   3
   2
   3

col =

   1
   2
   3

page =

   1
   1
   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach: compute differences along third dimension and detect when all those differences are zero:

```
result = ~any(diff(A,[],3),3);
```

Comment: Nice.  This probably has a lower memory footprint than `bsxfun`.

Comment: That's a nice and elegant way to do it

Comment: @Luis Mendo this looks great but do you know how I can adapt this if I have 2x5x7 (2 rows by 5 columns and 7 dimensions)  I got a little lost at what the 3 is representing my fault for doing 3x3x3 example.

Comment: @RickT Those two numbers `3` mean "third dimension", so it should work without changing anything, for any 3D array

Comment: @Luis Mendo I tried but I get an error in octave error in the line "result = ~any(diff(A,[],7),7);" error: DIM must be a valid dimension
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: called from:

Comment: @RickT As I said, don't change that 3. It means third dimension, not size of the the third dimension. So: use `result = ~any(diff(A,[],3),3)` for __any__ 3D array

Answer (score 5):

Use `bsxfun`([MATLAB doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [Octave doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html)) and check to see if broadcasting the first slice is equal across all slices with a call to `all`([MATLAB doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html), [Octave doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Finding-Elements-and-Checking-Conditions.html#XREFall)):

```
B = bsxfun(@eq, A, A(:,:,1));
result = all(B, 3);
```

If we're playing [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), a one liner could be:

```
result = all(bsxfun(@eq, A, A(:,:,1)), 3);
```

The beauty of the above approach is that you can have as many slices as you want in the third dimension, other than just three.

## Example

```
%// Your data
A(:,:,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 9 8]; 
A(:,:,2)=[9 1 7; 6 5 4; 7 2 8]; 
A(:,:,3)=[2 4 6; 8 9 1; 3 5 8];

B = bsxfun(@eq, A, A(:,:,1));
result = all(B, 3);
```

... gives us:

```
>> result

result =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
```

The above makes sense since the third row and third column for all slices is the only value where every slice shares this same value (i.e. 8).

Comment: this looks great but do you know how I can adapt this if I have 2x5x7 (2 rows by 5 columns and 7 dimensions)  I got a little lost at what the 3 is representing my fault for doing 3x3x3 example.

Comment: As long as you have a 3D matrix, this example should work.  I don't understand what you mean by "7 dimensions".  Do you mean 7 slices where each slice is 2 x 5?  Either my answer or Luis Mendo's will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
result = A(:,:,1) == A(:,:,2) & A(:,:,1) == A(:,:,3);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`sum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) the elements along the third dimension and divide it with the number of dimensions. We get back the original value if the values are the same in all dimension. Otherwise a different (e.g. a decimal) value. Then find the location where `A` and the summation are equal over the third dimension.

```
all( A == sum(A,3)./size(A,3),3)

ans =

0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   1
```

***or***

You could also do

```
all(A==repmat(sum(A,3)./size(A,3),[1 1 size(A,3)]),3)
```

where `repmat(sum(A,3)./size(A,3),[1 1 size(A,3)])` would highlight the implicit broadcasting of this when compared with `A`.

***or***

you skip the broadcasting altogether and just compare it with the first slice of `A`

```
A(:,:,1) == sum(A,3)./size(A,3)
```

---

#### Explanation

`3` represents the third dimension .
`sum(A,3)` means that we are taking the sum over the third dimension.
Then we divide that sum by the number of dimensions.
It's basically the average value for that position in the third dimension.
If you add three values and then divide it by three then you get the original value back.
For example, `A(3,3,:)` is `[8 8 8]`. `(8+8+8)/3 = 8`.
If you take another example, i.e. the value above, `A(2,3,:) = [6 4 1]`.
Then `(6+4+1)/3=3.667`. This is not equal to `A(2,3,:)`.

```
sum(A,3)./size(A,3)
ans =

   4.0000   2.3333   5.3333
   6.0000   6.3333   3.6667
   5.6667   5.3333   8.0000
```

Therefore, we know that the elements are not the same
throughout the third dimension. This is just a trick I use
to determine that. You also have to remember that
`sum(A,3)./size(A,3)` is originally a `3x3x1` matrix
that will be automatically expanded (i.e. broadcasted) to a
`3x3x3` matrix when we do the comparison with `A` (`A == sum(A,3)./size(A,3)`).
The result of that comparison will be a logical array with `1` for the positions that are the same throughout the third dimension.

```
A == sum(A,3)./size(A,3)
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   1

ans(:,:,2) =

   0   0   0
   1   0   0
   0   0   1

ans(:,:,3) =

   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   1
```

Then use `all(....,3)` to get those. The result is a `3x3x1`
matrix where a `1` indicates that the value is the same in the
third dimension.

```
all( A == sum(A,3)./size(A,3),3)
ans =

   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   1
```

Comment: this looks great but do you know how can adapt this if I have 2x5x7 (2 rows by 5 columns and 7 dimensions)  I got a little lost at what the 3 is representing my fault for doing 3x3x3 example.

Comment: I have just tried with a `2x5x4` example and that works too. It seems like there is a lot of confusion with this so I have added more explanations. I think `A(:,:,1) == sum(A,3)./size(A,3)` is the most efficient. Please see the updated post. Hope this helps...